# Share Power BI Datasets with Users Outside Organisation

Tags: powerbi

I've connected to an on premises SSAS data source with Power BI Desktop and could successfully publish to the web.

I would like to share the datasets themselves with users outside my organisation so that they can drag/drop the dimensions/measures and create reports and dashboards or reports that they would like to see.

From what I've read it's only possible to share preconfigured dashboards and reports with users outside my organisation. Could someone please tell me if it is possible to share the datasets themselves with users outside my organisation?

Comment: Multidimensional or Tabular SSAS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you help the external company setup an On premises data gateway on a VM in your network and help them get it connected to your cube the the external users can publish the Power BI Desktop report to their Power BI tenant. Is there role based security in your cube that would apply to external users? If so you will need to setup an [alternate UPN suffix](http://www.artisconsulting.com/blogs/greggalloway/2014/12/19/setting-up-a-demo-of-the-power-bi-analysis-services-connector) and user accounts for the external users on your domain as described here. Or you could setup [user mappings](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/power-bi-gateways-april-update/) to use CustomData to pass their username in to your cube that way. With CustomData you change your SSAS roles to have only a service account as a member (not real users) then use the [CustomData() MDX function in the dynamic security MDX](https://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2011/03/using-custom-data-to-securely-access-analysis-services-data-via-performancepoint/) expressions.

The whole scenario is described more fully [here](http://www.artisconsulting.com/blogs/greggalloway/2015/10/22/power-bi-analysis-services-connector-and-azure-active-directory-domain-services). Though I was talking about hosting in Azure with VMs joined to AAD Domain Services, you could so it with alternate UPN suffixes or CustomData in a regular Active Directory domain.

If your model is Tabular then Azure Analysis Services may greatly simplify the matter. If that's of interest let me know.

Comment: Thanks Greg. I came across your website in looking for a solution but most of it was lost on me since I've only recently started working with domain controllers etc. I'm working with Multidimensional data. Anyway I found a workaround please let me know what you think: 1. Create an account for external user in my domain in the admin section of office 365. 2. Add this user as an admin to the gateway in Power BI. 3. Add this same user to the domain to which the 'on premises' server running SSAS is joined and grant sufficient rights/roles in SSAS. That's it!

Comment: @BenjiKok basically you create a user for them and they log into your Power BI tenant. That should work. Only downside is that when they leave the external company you won't know to shut off their access. And they have to remember a different password. Otherwise I'd that's an acceptable solution then great!

Comment: thanks for your input. Do you know if it is possible to configure multiple gateways on one server? This will enable us to implement this solution for multiple clients.

Comment: @BenjiKok each VM can install only one gateway at the moment. But yes you could have one for you and one gateway for a client of yours as long as you are talking multiple VMs